# Firebase Security Rules to restrict user to view their own data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

My Firebase Database structures is as follows:

```
{
  "accounts" : {
    "API_Keys" : {
      "Unique ID over here" : {
        "api_key" : "None",
      }
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "Unique UID over here" : {
      "email" : "abc@gmail.com",
      "username": "abc",
      "age": "18"
    },

  }
}
```

I have implemented the following security rules for this.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "accounts": {
     "API_Keys":{
       "$uid":{
       ".read": "$uid === auth.uid && auth != null ",
       ".write": "$uid === auth.uid && auth != null"
       }

     }
    },
     "users": {
       "$uid":{
       ".read": "$uid === auth.uid && auth != null ",
       ".write": "$uid === auth.uid && auth != null"
       }
    } 
  }
}
```

The user is going to link in his personal details and also an API Key. No user should be allowed to access any one else's keys somehow. Are the above rules satisfactory for this? Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It looks OK to me, though usually you reverse the order of the test to `"auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"`, as seen in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security#section-structuring-db).  You can test for yourself using the rules simulator in the Firebase console.

Comment: In the documentation I saw a triple equality sign("==="). Does it matter if we use two or three?

Comment: No.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#_equals